# Filtering Combinations

Tags: python, filter, combinations

I'm very new to programming. I'm trying to filter out combinations that only contains a certain number in python.

From below I only want the combinations that contains 6 to print.

```
list_5 = itertools.combinations(range(1, 30), 5)
```

I've tried this from another post and a lot of others. Nothing seems to work. Any help is appreciated

```
combo = [tuple for tuple in itertools.combinations(range(1, 30), 5)
     if len(x for x in tuple) == 6]
print (combo)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to python so I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it but this is how I personally would do it to make the code more understandable.

```
import itertools
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        list_5 = set(itertools.combinations(range(1, 30), 5)) # combinations from 5 elements containing numbers 1-30
        combo = [] 
        for seq in list_5: # check each sequence in the list
            for el in seq: # check each element in the sequence
                if el == 6:
                    combo.append(seq) # push/add the sequence containing 6 into combo
                    break # once we've found 6, we don't need to keep checking this seq, so we move on to the next one
        print(combo) # result
```

The result might seem squished together so you could print 2 sequences in a newline (but then that turns out to be very long so take your pick)

```
i = 1
    for seq in combo:
        if i < 2:
            print(seq, "   ", end = "") # to prevent newline
            i = i + 1
        elif i == 2:
            print(seq)
            i = 1
```

Comment: Nice solution. Keep in mind that using `set()` here is not needed - the output of itertools.combinations() is guaranteed to not contain duplicates if the input doesn't have duplicates. The third line can be simplified to `list_5 = itertools.combinations(range(1, 30), 5)`